# fetch Resources return -1 although there is resources - arcgis javascript

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, tsx

hey everyone im trying to retrive all reosureces that are in a portal item using the fetchResources function but it return

```
nextStart : -1
resources: []
total: 0
```

although there is resources in the portal item
what im doing wrong?

```
  const item = new PortalItem({
    id: "0890f410a5314b448528f059e3083261",
    portal
  });
  await item.load();
  console.log(item.fetchResources());
```

Resources:
[image: Resources and item id]

Answer (score 0):

Those "tables" are not "resources" in the context of an ArcGIS portal item. The specific resources for an item depends on the item type.  See for example https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/item-resources.htm

If you're trying to get to the data inside those tables, you probably want to create FeatureLayers that point to these tables (aka non-spatial layers).

Ref:
[https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#:~:text=The%20layer%20can%20be%20either%20a%20spatial%20(has%20geographic%20features)%20or%20non%2Dspatial%20(table)](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#:%7E:text=The%20layer%20can%20be%20either%20a%20spatial%20(has%20geographic%20features)%20or%20non%2Dspatial%20(table)).

Answer (score 0):

The way you use fetchResources is wrong. For asynchronous method you need to use await

```
const resourcesResponse = await item.fetchResources();
const resources = resourcesResponse.resources;
console.log(resources);
```